# If X is Beta distributed, what is distribution of Y: Y=1 for X>0.5 and Y=0 otherwise

Tags: distributions, random-variable, bernoulli-distribution, beta-distribution

Consider random variable $X \sim \mathrm{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$

What is the distribution of $Y$ defined by $Y\in \{0,1\}$, $Y=1$ if $X>0.5$ and $Y=0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$Y$ is obviously Bernoulli distributed, with the probability $p=P(Y=1)$ equal to $P(X>0.5)$, i.e.
$$\int_{0.5}^1 f(x)\ dx$$
where $f(x)$ is the pdf of the $\mathrm{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$ distribution.

I'm sure you can work it out from here :)